# How to find the most general value of $\cos(A-B) = 1/2$ and $\sin(A+B) =1/2$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I'm learning Trigonometry right now with myself and at current about general solution. I have a question which is confusing me from some time. The question is - 
$If \cos(A-B) = 1/2$ and $\sin(A+B) =1/2$, *find  the smallest  positive  value  of  A  and B  and  also  their  most  general  values.* 
I am getting $A=105^\circ$ and $B=45^\circ$,the answer of general value given in my book is [image: Image 1]

Please help. Thankyou in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you find $\cos \theta =\cos x$ just remember that $\theta= 2n\pi \pm x$ and if $\sin\theta =\sin x$ then $\theta = n\pi+(-1)^n x$.
In both the cases $n$ is an integer.

In the given problem $$A-B=2n\pi \pm \frac{\pi}{3}$$ and $$A+B=m\pi + (-1)^m\frac{\pi}{6}$$

Hope you can solve it now.

Comment: Oh. How can I be so fool. Thankyou.

Comment: @Shaswata                                                                                       
Can you please clarify why did you consider x to be 30 degrees when you were generalising the value of sin(A+B) when we found A+B = 150 degrees?